# Odoo installation ''error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to start up Odoo on a local server using VM VirtualBox.
I am using this to set everything up.

[Installing Odoo](https://github.com/jam-odoo/odoo-technical-training/wiki/Deploying-Installing-Odoo-(10c)-on-Ubuntu-16.04-LTS-Server-:-Linux-Reference)
I am stuck on step 11. It keeps telling me that the port is being used. I have tried:

```
ps aux | grep odoo
sudo kill <process id>
```

And then restarting but it does not shut down. Anyone understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
<pre>
./odoo-bin
2018-10-12 21:14:30,923 1423 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0
2018-10-12 21:14:30,924 1423 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons', '/home/odoo/odoo/addons', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons']
2018-10-12 21:14:30,924 1423 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2018-10-12 21:14:31,070 1423 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2018-10-12 21:14:31,190 1423 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.models.res_currency: The num2words python library is not installed, amount-to-text features won't be fully available.
Exception in thread odoo.service.httpd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 256, in http_thread
    self.httpd = ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable(self.interface, self.port, app)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 104, in __init__
    handler=RequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 440, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 114, in server_bind
    super(ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable, self).server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 454, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a process running on the Odoo port which default it's using 8069. You could check the ports usage with the following command

```
netstat -lp --inet
```

To see what process it's using the odoo port to be able to kill it. To kill it you need to send a termination signal to the process. I recomend you to use 9, like:

```
kill -9 pid
```

Where pid is the process id. You could also use htop to be able to search the process and kill it using the htop UI commands

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message another process is listening on port 8069. You can start Odoo on another port using the following command:

```
--xmlrpc-port <port>
```

You can also change the port in the Odoo configuration file. According the tutorial you used, it is `/home/odoo/odoo.conf`. Open the file, find and modify the `xmlrpc_port = 8069` line, and restart the Odoo instance.

Answer (score 0):

try to run the server with this command :

`./odoo-bin --xmlrpc-port=8012`